# Toggle ALT key in Baldur's Gate 3

Tags: autohotkey

I tried to toggle <kbd>ALT</kbd> in Baldur's Gate 3 but no joy:

```
Down := false

*F2::
Down := !Down
If Down
    Send {ALT Down}
else
    Send {ALT Up}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

This is in fact correct answer, use f9 to toggle.

```
    Down := false
    
    *F9::
    Down := !Down
    If Down
        Send {ALT Down}
    else
        Send {ALT Up}
    return
```